# Good book or other resource on integration testing?

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing

There are enough books on how to do unit testing.

Do you know any good books (or other good resources) on integration testing?

What I am particularly interested in is

- Define scope (unit testing < integration testing < automated func. testing
- What is a good and bad integration test
- Data access
- Service layers
- Configuration
- Spring or other DI containers for integration testing
- ...

?

Comment: hi just curious did you manage to find anything besides those two?

Answer (score 2):

**Continous Integration** By Duvall, Matyas and Glover
It's a Martin Fowler's signature book published by Addison-Wesley
It might give you some nice ideas.

Comment: @Julien Grenier: Looking through the contents, haven't found much on integration testing TECHNIQUES...

Answer (score 1):

I like "Test Driven Development: By Example" ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)).

Kent Beck is a good writer and obviously knows what he is talking about.

Comment: @Gunnar Steinn: this looks like a TDD (unit testing) book to me?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another thread on this which is pretty good:
[The Agile Way: Integration Testing vs Functional Testing or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555899/the-agile-way-integration-testing-vs-functional-testing-or-both)