# TDD integration testing

Tags: tdd, integration-testing

I'm rather new to the world of TDD, and have a couple questions about integration tests.  First, what is the diff btwn an integration test and functional test (I have heard that a functional test is a kind of integration test, but then I don't know what other kinds there are).  Also what exactly should be tested in an integration test?   Just site links?  Or also tiny details like words on the page and style?

Comment: This might help you with the first question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670729/what-is-the-difference-between-integration-testing-and-functional-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a globally accepted definition for these terms. Other commonly debated terms include the difference between a unit test and an acceptance test.

I don't think it's productive to try to define them either. Instead, I think you'll do best if you define terms for test types used within the context of your system/organisation, possibly using the link provided by @RishiRock as inspiration.

Comment: +1 very wise advice unless you want to spend your days arguing with & confusing one another because of the 20 different interpretations of 'integration test'!