# Unit testing in PHP frameworks

Tags: php, unit-testing, frameworks

When working with PHP frameworks, do I have to conceive unit tests for controllers and other pieces.

I don't know if it amounts to testing the frameworks components what are already well-tested.

My question is what type of code is supposed to be unit-tested, when working with PHP framworks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You never write unit tests for controllers; you write integration tests for them. Regardless of the framework, all controllers should have integration tests.

Comment: DO you mean functional tests ?

Comment: Yes and no. Functional and integration tests aren't exactly the same, technicallly, but do have enough in common for the two terms to be used as equivalents in many cases. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670729/what-is-the-difference-between-integration-testing-and-functional-testing) might be interesting :).